# date format function

Tags: php, date, format

Maybe is a dumb question, but I can't find the proper function:

I have a string date like `04/05/2012`

How I can pass to this format: `2012-04-05 20:18:11` to insert in mySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combination of date and strtotime ...

```
$my_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('04/05/2012'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($your_time_string);
echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

Time can not be 'made' on its own. If you're however inserting the current date-time setting, then the following code will be used:

```
$dt = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", time() );
```

You may use `dleiftah`'s statement, but the time in that case will always be `00:00:00`